# after packing python file with pyinstaller, the created runable file dump

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyinstaller

i run my python file, which works as read data from excel file and insert data into mysql, in python:3.8, it works well.
after i packed the file with pyinstaller, and it runs bad. returns like

```
Requested Module was not found: No module named 'mysql.connector.plugins.caching_sha2_password'
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "insert_dwi.py", line 60, in <module>
    connection_pool = mysql.connector.pooling.MySQLConnectionPool(
  File "mysql/connector/pooling.py", line 430, in __init__
  File "mysql/connector/pooling.py", line 538, in add_connection
  File "mysql/connector/pooling.py", line 294, in connect
  File "mysql/connector/connection.py", line 172, in __init__
  File "mysql/connector/connection.py", line 636, in close
  File "mysql/connector/connection.py", line 1155, in cmd_quit
  File "mysql/connector/network.py", line 604, in send
  File "mysql/connector/network.py", line 221, in send
  File "mysql/connector/network.py", line 167, in _send_pkt
  File "mysql/connector/errors.py", line 54, in __init__
  File "mysql/connector/locales/__init__.py", line 62, in get_client_error
ImportError: No localization support for language 'eng'
[23428] Failed to execute script 'insert_dwi' due to unhandled exception!
```

please locate the problem.

i run the python file in windows and linux, both are run well.
my code about the mysql config:

```
db_config_test = {
    'host': '127.0.0.1',
    'user': 'root',
    'port': '3306',
    'password': '123456',
    'database': 'dwi_test'
}

connection_pool = mysql.connector.pooling.MySQLConnectionPool(
    pool_name="my_pool",
    pool_size=5,
    **db_config_test
)
```

Comment: [Helping PyInstaller Find Modules](https://pyinstaller.org/en/stable/when-things-go-wrong.html#helping-pyinstaller-find-modules)

Comment: i do not solve this problem. but i change the pack tool to cx_freeze, also its pack has the same problem "No module named 'mysql.connector.plugins.caching_sha2_password'". finally i add the whole "/mysql/connector/plugins" to the created libs by hands and it starts work normally.

Answer (score 2):

Python when adding packages can be tricky at times! **Usually the problem is ownership of the folder it is trying to install in.** Ownership basically checks who created the folder and under certain conditions it will not let you read or write, like:

- the creator specified the file/folder to be locked,
- your computer username is different to the one specified on the folder you are trying to install into.

For the solution, there is 2:

1. install on to a global open path, or
2. run this command if you are on mac: `chflags -R` *path of install location*. Also remember to copy your site-packages folder over into the destination.
3. if on windows you can go into properties of the file/folder and change the admin ownership/rights in there.